# Changing Kafka Configuration on spotify/kafka Dockerfile

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to change the configuration of Kafka that is inside this public docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/kafka/

I'm trying to connect to the container with:

```
docker exec -ti <CONTAINER_ID> bash
```

But I cannot find where the server.properties is.

Comment: `find . -name server.properties`

Comment: Thanks Oliver, but still getting nothing.

Comment: I just ran that inside that container and got `./opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/config/server.properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server.properties` file is inside the `$KAFKA_HOME/config/` directory.

This variable is in [Dockerfile](https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka/blob/master/kafka/Dockerfile#L8), and is used in `start-kafka.sh` [script](https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka/blob/fc8cdbd2e23a5cac21e7138d07ea884b4309c59a/kafka/scripts/start-kafka.sh#L75).